# set the src attribute of an iframe, then load into page, using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, search, iframe, youtube

I'm currently working on a simple google chrome extension to play youtube videos in a separate tab based on an [omnibox query](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox.html). For example, if a user searches for "tupac", my extension redirects to chrome-extension://{chrome-extension-id}/just-play-music.html?tupac.

Now I want to embed a youtube iframe player on this just-play-music.html page, set to play a list of videos returned by a search on the string "tupac". Following the Google API docs, this is achieved easily enough by providing the following src url for my iframe: http://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=search&list=QUERY where QUERY in this case would be replaced by "tupac".

However, here is where I've reached a sticking point. I can't figure out how to configure my .html and .js files so that this happens dynamically when the page loads, based on the url of the page. Below is the code for just-play-music.html and the .js file it is linked to.

Again, the goal here is to generate a youtube iframe with a src attribute created by grabbing location.search (I realize this is an inelegant way of doing this) when the page loads, and then insert this iframe into the content section.  Please let me know if you see something very wrong, this is admittedly my first time working with javascript.

html

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="header">
    <h1>just play music:</h1>
  </section>

  <section id="movie" class="content">
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
function iframeDidLoad() {
alert("Done");
}

function loadIframe() {
    var query = location.search;
    var target = "http://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=search&autoplay=1&list=" +         encodeURIComponent(query);
    var frame = '<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"    src="'+target+'" frameborder="0" />';
    document.getElementById('movie').innerHTML = frame;
    iframeDidLoad();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do a `console.log` on the `location.search`. It gives you a string you need to parse, e.g., `"?key=value&key2=value2&etc=another+value"`. I think you might need to address that.

So if where it says `list=` needs to be just `tupac`, you're going to need to convert your search string from a string that looks like this: `?query=tupac` to a string that looks like this `tupac` by doing something like:

```
var query = location.search.split('=')[1];
```

What this does is it splits the string up into two pieces, using the `=` sign to divide them, then using `[1]` to select the second piece (array indices start from 0). Then you'll have just the `tupac` portion of the string (or whatever the query string is for [e.g., `U2`]).

If your query string has multiple parameters, you needs to parse each of those first, e.g., if your query string looks like this:

`?somekey=somevalue&query=tupac&someotherkey=some+other+value`

you're going to need to do something like this:

```
var query;
location.search.split('&').forEach(function(piece) {
    if (piece.indexOf('query=') !== -1)
        query = piece.split('=')[1];
});
```